# Arch Giving me a Black Screen with fixed white underscore after update

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, boot

Almost certain it's something to do with discrete/integrated Nvidia and Intel GPUs.
Ran pacman -Syu last night, went to turn on my laptop this morning and it wouldn't boot.  Turning off quiet in grub gives me a bunch of green [ OK ] messages, after which I'm back to the initial screen with the (non flashing) cursor.

Using nomodeset, i915.modeset=0 and nouveau.modeset=0 allows me to access a TTY but I'm stil unsure how to fix this.  Couldn't find anything of interest in XORG logs, should I check anything else?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have enough rep to add a comment, so I had to put it as an answer.

If it's working before and suddenly broke, may be you encountered this bug https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64805 ?